# C - memcpy and copying structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct, free, memcpy

Ran into a design problem when using `memcpy` and building a generic HashTable in c.  The HashTable maps `unsigned int` keys to `void *` data that I `memcpy` over.

```
// Random example
void foo() {

  // Suppose `a` is a struct that contains LinkedLists, char arrays, etc
  // within it.
  struct *a = malloc(sizeof(a));
  HashTable ht = ht_create(sizeof(a));

  // Insert the (key, value) pair (0, a) into the hash table ht
  ht_insert(ht, 0, a);

  // Prevent memory leak
  destroy_struct(a);

  // Do stuff...

  // ... eventually destroy ht
  ht_destroy(ht);
}
```

Now, given `struct a` has LinkedLists and pointers within it, and the HashTable is using `memcpy`, my understanding is that it copies over shallow copies of these pointers.  Thus, `ht_insert` mallocs space for a new entry, shallowly copies over data from `a`, and inserts the new entry into its table.

Consequently, unless I free `struct a` completely with some function `destroy_struct`, I am leaking memory.  However, given I'm shallowly copying data in `ht_insert`, when I call `destroy_struct(a)`, I will have accidentally freed the data pointed to within the hash table's entry as well!

Is the logic above correct, and if so, should I use a some recursive memcpy function that makes sure to deep copy all data from `struct a` to the HashTable?

Comment: `ht_insert` has only two argument `(key, value)` but you have written three `(ht, 0, a)` Is it mistake or I m not getting it ?

Comment: First one is the hash table, second two are the key and value.

Comment: @sir_thursday You copy data from `a` to HashTable using `memcpy` ?

Comment: Yes, I was doing that because I naively thought that `memcpy` always deep copies data.  I just realized now that of course this is not always the case.

Comment: @sir_thursday And why do you think that ?

Comment: memcpy deep copies the memory pointed to by `src` to `dest`.  If the data pointed to by `src` is pointers to different data, then the pointers themselves are copied to `dest`.  Thus, if you try to free the memory at `src` afterwards, `dest` will point to free'd memory.

Comment: Can I look at definition of `destroy_struct` ?

Comment: @ameyCU A memcpy() operation is an example of a shallow copy. [refer](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13625)

Comment: In this code example you are not allocating any more memory, so you could just use `free(a)` instead of `destroy_struct(a)` surely?

Comment: @immibis: I was thinking about that, just wasn't sure if it is the "correct way" to go about doing this.  Definitely makes sense though.

Comment: @punit vara: `destroy_struct` would simply be freeing individual properties within `a`, and then freeing `a` itself.

Comment: okay . I think you have got solution .Good luck with that :-)

Comment: Yes, if you are using destroy_struct, you ought to have some kind of copy_struct too. But you may consider storing pointers to your structures, rather than structures themselves. In this case you need neither copy nor destroy.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, if your code doesn't reproduce the problem you are explaining, you shouldn't include it. The problem your code produces is compiler errors. This doesn't help your question, does it?

> Now, given struct a has LinkedLists and pointers within it, and the HashTable is using memcpy, my understanding is that it copies over shallow copies of these pointers.

If you are simply copying the internal representation of a `struct whatever *` into the internal representation of a `void *`, then you are asking for trouble. There is no guarantee that the two representations are identical. It's possible that one pointer type might be larger than the other, that they use different *endianness* (if they're implemented as typical quasi-integers) or other internal differences might exist. You should convert one pointer to the other type, and then you could simply assign it... In fact, because one of the types is `void *` that conversion will happen implicitly *when* you assign.

> Consequently, unless I free `struct a` completely with some function `destroy_struct`, I am leaking memory.

From what you have described, you should only call `free` on that pointer value **once** (and only **once**) you are done with it, and your program no longer has any use for it (e.g. *after* you have removed it from the hashtable). This goes for all non-null pointers that are returned by `malloc`, `realloc` or `calloc`. **To clarify: if `x` and `y` store the same pointer returned by one of those functions, `free` should only be called *ONCE* on *ONE OF THEM* because they contain the same value.**

> Is the logic above correct, and if so, should I use a some recursive memcpy function that makes sure to deep copy all data from struct a to the HashTable?

I highly recommend breaking this question up into two or more separate questions, because it's double-barreled. I could simply answer "yes" (or "no"). Would that give you any meaningful information?

This brings me back to what I first wrote. I can only guide you based on what you've written here, which might not be reflective of the code that you use (especially given the influences of the erroneous code you've given). In order to guide you better, I would need to see all of the gaps filled in. I would need to see a testcase that creates a hashtable, inserts into the hashtable, uses the hashtable, removes from the hashtable and cleans up the hashtable to determine whether or not your operations are leaking anywhere... **but most importantly, this testcase would need to be *COMPILABLE*!** Otherwise it can't do any of those things, because it can't compile.

Comment: I appreciate the time you took to write up this answer, lots of great info in here... especially to a new C programmer as myself.  At the same time, I don't think the "pseudo" example code I included was useless at all.  I think it helped to convey the design problem I was running into.  The code snippet's purpose was not to be fully compilable with test cases, it was simply to help describe the problem.

Moreover, perhaps instead of posting a large rant intertwined with your answer, post a comment first asking for more information.

Comment: @sir_thursday If your example is to be considered useful, then surely it wouldn't hurt to make your example compilable...

Comment: It's just pseudo code!  I'd need to post a bunch of code for it to be compilable!  There's no rule again this on StackOverflow... no need to be such a stickler.

Comment: @sir_thursday Well, your "pseudocode" introduces confusion to your question in a number of ways... I'm just sayin'... Also, you shouldn't need to fill in more than three lines per blank.